# Found my dog laying in street, what happened

Tags: dogs, death

I let my dog out for what seemed only a few mins, maybe less then 10 min. I had been training him to stay in the yard, but I was so busy doing laundry, I thought I'll let him out really quick and put one load in then run out to check on him. I went out and found him laying in street. He had a heart beat but his tongue was hanging out with a small a mount of blood coming from his mouth. He looked perfectly in on piece, I wasn't even sure if he was hit by car but he had a glazed over look in his eyes and his body was limp when I picked him up.

I rushed him to the vet, but they couldn't save him. Dr only said he was able to revive him but wasn't sure what had happened and I didn't know either being that I wasn't out there. My guilt overwhelms me day and night. I cry all day long, I can't sleep. He was the best dog, little yorkie poodle mix with so much love to give. He was a stray that I had picked up because I wanted to give him a good life but he ended up dead on street anyway. Can anyone tell me what might have happened. Was he hit by car but no signs of being ran over. I don't get it. I want closure.

Comment: These things do happen - don't beat yourself up trying to figure out how. The closure is knowing that you loved your dog and your dog loved you while you were fortunate enough to have one another. So very saddened to hear of your sudden and tragic loss - even in the best circumstances, pets have the worst habit of not living forever. Google "rainbow bridge" - it's okay to cry. When the time is right, get another dog and honor the memory of the friend who is gone. Kindest regards.

Comment: Even I had a stray pup who looked lost. Always used to stay in my garage right when I went out and would jump on me when I came back. All was well till one night he was very dull and shaky and refused to eat Next day he didn't come out of the car beneath which he used to sleep. Later when I returned home came to know he passed away. No matter what he was one of the good strays i had but stayed only for 2-3 months. Having a dog is good but giving stray a loving home is an ultimate experience which you get.

Comment: I want to thank each and everyone of you for all your kind words. Your words have brought me closer to working on my guilt and closer to healing. My days and nights still feel so empty and this house seems so cold and dead without my Mr. X. He would bring this house alive with all the love he gave and all his playfulness. At times it really felt as though he was thanking me for giving him a home with all the love he gave. He truly was such a lover always nibbling on my ear and giving me kisses. I miss that and still cry daily. I would give anything to hold him one more time and tell him how mu

Comment: What helped my wife and I get over the death of our female Bichon Frise was adopting another dog (an older, neutered male miniature poodle). We're smiling again. :-)

Comment: @E.G. take care. The loss of a pet is devastating.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sorry for your loss.

This can only ever be speculation, but given how quick it was it's likely the dog was hit by a car (or some other forceful impact, but that's a hideous thought). Any ingestion of poison or possible snake bite would take longer than that to cause such limpness and will often cause seizures.

Without seeing what happened, and no autopsy, no one can give you that definitive answer. Try to forgive yourself, we all carry regrets and make mistakes.

Please take these wise words [from the comments](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17046/found-my-dog-laying-in-street-what-happened/17049?noredirect=1#comment22046_17049) by [mhwombat](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/982/mhwombat)

> Please remember that once you adopted him, he had a life filled with
>   love. That's more important than the length of his life. I hope that
>   when you are ready, you adopt another pet. You clearly have a lot of
>   love and compassion to give to an animal that needs it.